# SQL | Joining and renaming databases

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables medlem, funktion and children. I have to join all three tables together and print out everything they say. Medlem and funktion share "ID" as primary key. However the table children has two columns called cid and pid which stands for childrenID and parentID. I think I have to rename cid and pid to "id" so medlem and funktion understand what it is.

```
SELECT * 
FROM medlem 
   NATURAL JOIN funktion 
   NATURAL JOIN children 
where cid and pid = id;
```

This is what it prints http://gyazo.com/1880e8806f67576db8a84d995cf1aa98
The thing is it's over 100 members in the database and I only get 11 results. If a member isn't a parent or a child it should be blank, but if they are the child/parent should be listed as a number(id).

English isn't my native language so if you don't understand what I need help with just ask!

Comment: Don't use 'NATURAL JOIN' unless the column names are exact - and if you do use, specify the [same-named] columns to join on anyway. It's easiest just to use a normal inner join (eg. `..JOIN funktion f ON f.id = m.cid..`) , and it makes everything much more explicit/clear. Note the use of an alias (`f`) and explicit column identification (`f.id`) above.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. New to SQL, but I think it's awesome so doing my best!

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting all of your records because you're only getting records that are a parent or child.  You need to do an outer join to get the records that are neither.  Something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT m.*, f.*, c1.pid, c2.cid
FROM medlem m
JOIN funktion f ON f.id = m.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN children c1 ON c1.cid = m.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN children c2 ON c2.pid = m.id;
```